# Visualizing a Scalar Field: $T(x,y,z)=10e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

Tags: graphing-functions, scalar-fields

For a scalar field of temperature, for example, let 
$$T(x,y,z)=10e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$ 
where $T(x,y,z)$ is a function of temperature in terms of position variables $x, y$ and $z$. How can we visualize this?

I have seen in textbooks where they represented a scalar field as a 3D diagram, but surely the above function is 4-dimensional?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's like the weather map on tv. They show a map of the area with a little number at various points indicating the temp there. In 3D it's the same. Visualize space, and at each point there's a little number showing the temp. And a cute weather person explaining it to the audience.

Comment: @user4894 I guess yes, I do see what you mean, but am I right in thinking that the T(x,y,z) function I defined above should give us a 4-dimensional graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider some cuts in the domain, for example for $x=$ constant or similar cutting plane.

[image]